# Creating table from API

Tags: javascript, html, function, html-table

My function is pulling information from an api and then putting it into the table. For some reason this function is not working.

this is my function:

```
    function getPayInfo(socCode) {
        var apiurl = "http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/ashe/estimatePay?soc=";
        var apicall = apiurl + socCode;
        $.get(apicall, function(data) {
            $("#Pay tbody").html("");
            $.each(data.years, function(i, e) {
                var tablerow = $("<tr></tr>");
                tablerow.append("<td>" + e.year + "</td>");
                tablerow.append("<td>" + e.estpay + "</td>");
                $("#Pay tbody").append(tablerow);
            });
        }); 
    }
```

and this is the table I am putting it into:

```
    <div class="well table table-stripped">
        <h4>Pay Information</h4>
        <h5>Pounds per Week</h5>
        <table id="Pay">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Estimate Pay</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I expected it to return a year and data value into the table. if you take the url in the function and add a certain 4 figure value (the socCode) (e.g. 5113) to the end it will give the data online this should then be returned to the table body.

Comment: What is it returning / what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you debugged/examined the data structure inside your `$.get` callback? It looks to me that your access method is incorrect. When I access your [example url](http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/ashe/estimatePay?soc=5113), I get the following data back:

```
{
  "soc":5113,
  "series":[
     {
       "year":2012,
       "estpay":340
     }
   ]
 }
```

I think you want your iterator to be this instead:

```
// there is no data.years
$.each(data.series, function(i, e) {
   ...
```

This should make your `e` param be of the form `{year: 2012, estpay: 340}`, which appears to be what you want to interpret it as.

Comment: Thank you that was the problemb. i have now solved it, thanks again :)